# Celery periodic task not periodic

Tags: python, redis, celery

I tried to create a task that should run every minute in celery along with redis server

To execute redis I ran `"redis-server"`

To execute celery I ran `"celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info"`

This is my tasks.py file

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='1')),name="run_every_minute",ignore_result=True)
def run_every_minute():
    print("hehe")
    return "ok"
```

When I ran in python console

```
from tasks.py import run_every_minute
z=run_every_minute.delay()
```

I got output at celery running terminal as

```
[2019-06-05 01:35:02,591: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: run_every_minute[06498b4b-1d13-45af-b91c-fb10476e0aa3]
[2019-06-05 01:35:02,595: WARNING/Worker-2] hehe 
[2019-06-05 01:35:02,599: INFO/MainProcess] Task run_every_minute[06498b4b-1d13-45af-b91c-fb10476e0aa3] succeeded in
    0.004713802001788281s: 'ok'
```

But this should execute every minute since its a periodic task. How this can happen.
Also, how can we execute a celery task at some specific time say 5:30 GMT(for example).

Comment: That log only shows a few milliseconds, so we can't tell if the task would have repeated after a minute.

Comment: There is no log after this last one. its currently 1:47 and no new log entry

Comment: did you check if run_every needs to the scheduler be started [Periodic Task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you? How to check?

Comment: Periodic Task need the scheduler/beat be started, i dont know if `run_every` property is a necesary a schedule/periodic task, try doing `celery -A tasks beat` along side of `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info`

Comment: it didn't work. Still executed only once

Comment: @Patricio It worked but I noticed it printed after every hour, not every  minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on the commentary

First `periodic_task` needs the scheduler/beat be started ([Periodic Tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler)), with this the scheduler will send the task depending in the `run_every` parameter

`celery -A tasks beat`

Next, if you need to send the beat every minute, you need the crontab be like this

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*')),name="run_every_minute",ignore_result=True)
def run_every_minute():
    print("hehe")
    return "ok"
```

With `minute='*'`, it will send the task every minute.  `minute=1` will send the task at every hour in the minute one

Answer (score 1):

Answering your last comment:

```
run_every=(crontab(minute='1'))
```

You have specified 'minute of hour' = 1, so celery beat runs your periodic task every hour at minute '1', e.g. 00:01, 01:01 and so on.

You should set `hour` attribute for your crontab, propably as a range